# Criar um Executar Classe

Tags: java

Preciso de ajuda para executar uma classe, é um exercício da faculdade, eu não sei como finalizar.
Falta somente esta última classe para finalizar o projeto.

Preciso criar uma classe `TesteProjeto` com a estrutura `main`.

Nesta estrutura eu preciso chamar uma classe e já passar os parâmetros nela. 
Como eu faço isto?

Segue o que eu já fiz:

```
public class OrdemServico {
    private int id;
    private long dataSolicitacao;
    private long dataInicio;
    private long dataFim;
    private double ValorTotal;

    private Cliente cliente; 
    private Atendente atendente; 
    private Tecnico tecnico; 
    private Material material; 
    private Servico servico; 

        public OrdemServico(int id, long dataSolicitacao, long dataInicio, long dataFim, double ValorTotal, String cliente, String atendente, String tecnico, String Material, String Servico)
        {
            // inicializa variáveis de instância
            this.id = id;
            this.dataSolicitacao = dataSolicitacao;
            this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
            this.dataFim = dataFim;
            this.ValorTotal = ValorTotal;
            //this.cliente = new Cliente();
            //this.cliente = cliente.getNome();
        }

        public void exibeInformacoes(){
            System.out.println("OrdemServico: ");
            System.out.println("ID: " + id);
            System.out.println("Data Solicitacao: " + dataSolicitacao);
            System.out.println("Data Inicio: " + dataInicio);
            System.out.println("Data Fim: " + dataFim);
            System.out.println("Valor Total: " + ValorTotal);

            System.out.println("Cliente: " + cliente);
            System.out.println("Atendente: " + atendente);
            System.out.println("Tecnico: " + tecnico);
            System.out.println("Material: " + material);
            System.out.println("Servico: " + servico);
        }
    }
```

Agora preciso fazer o `main`. O que eu já fiz, mas está um pouco errado:

```
class TesteProjeto
{ // classe de testes
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        OrdemServico ordem = new OrdemServico();
        System.out.println("Teste");
    }
}
```

Podem me ajudar em como fazer?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que quer, mas basicamente é só chamar o construtor que você criou passando os argumentos que deseja, é isto que não sabe fazer?

Comment: Você não demonstrou ou mencionou isso na pergunta, então a pergunta não está clara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde,

O motivo do "erro" é por conta de você estar instanciando o objeto OrdemServico com um construtor vazio

```
OrdemServico ordem = new OrdemServico();
```

O Java por padrão sempre mantém um construtor vazio e public em todas as classes, mesmo quando não declarado, por conta disso, seu objeto está sendo iniciado sem dados.

Para resolver basta inserir os dados na hora de instanciar o objeto da seguinte forma, seguindo a declaração de parametros do seu construtor:

```
OrdemServico ordem = new OrdemServico(1, 20052019, 20052019, 22052019, 50.00, "Orivaldo", "Maria", "Reinaldo", "Material X,Y,Z", "Serviço 1");
```

Desta forma você está populando seu objeto OrdemServico com dados e quando pedir para fazer a impressão do mesmo, ele o fará corretamente.

Comment: *"O Java por padrão sempre mantém um construtor vazio"* - Na verdade o construtor padrão sem parâmetros só é criado por *default* se nenhum outro construtor for definido. Mas nesse caso já foi definido um construtor com vários parâmetros, então o construtor *default* sem parâmetros não existe e `new OrdemServico()` não compila.

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira criar um objeto já passando os dados, os informe no construtor, conforme abaixo.

Para exibir os dados chame a classe com o método `exibeInformacoes()`, conforme abaixo.

```
class TesteProjeto
{   classe de testes
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        OrdemServico ordem = new OrdemServico(1, 20052019, 20052019, 22052019, 50.00, "Orivaldo", "Maria", "Reinaldo", "Material X,Y,Z", "Serviço 1");

        ordem.exibeInformacoes();
        System.out.println("Teste");
    }
}
```